# 240gb SSD suddenly think it's my 120gb SSD

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, boot, ssd

I have two SSDs:

- **Drive 120:** 120gb SSD Sandisk
- **Drive 240:** 240gb SSD Sandisk

Windows 10 is installed on the Drive 240.

To get to Windows 10, I had to select Drive 120 from the BIOS boot manager to get to a Windows Boot Manager that would let me select Windows 10.

There was a blue screen error while using the computer and upon restarting drive 240 disappeared from BIOS. Selecting drive 120 would attempt to get to what I believe was the Windows Boot Manager screen as it usually did, but it would lock up and quickly restart.

When I plug drive 240 into other systems, it does not show up in file explorer, but it does show up in device manager. **In device manager, it has the same label as drive 120. It shows up as Sandisk 120gb SSD** The volume of drive 240 is not displayed. The adapter being used works with other SSDs (they show up in file explorere)

What can I do to (solutions for any the following):

- Get data from drive 240
- Make drive 240 into something that drive 120 can once again boot into it
- Repair it so it can boot by itself

Screenshots: (I can no longer connect both at the same time with Windows running because I had to use one of the SATA cables for the new SSD since the 240gb SSD is not being recognized).

**DISK MANAGEMENT SCREENSHOTS:**

- http://ibb.co/dqWhUG - 120gb Plugged In - Disk Management
- http://ibb.co/eKFnww - 240gb Plugged in - Disk Management

**DEVICE MANAGER SCREENSHOTS:**

- http://ibb.co/bvXZbw - 120gb Plugged In - Device Manager
- http://ibb.co/cssBOb - 240gb Plugged In - Device Manager
- http://ibb.co/dSsjbw - Neither Plugged In - Device Manager

---

MORE INFO IF NEEDED:

When I installed Windows 10 on Drive 240, to boot to it I had to select Drive 120 from the BIOS boot manager to get to a Windows boot manager that let me select and boot to Windows 10.

I deleted the information on Drive 120 while in Drive 240 one day, and tried to boot directly to Drive 240, but I still had to select Drive 120 from the BIOS boot manager to get to the Windows boot manager to select and boot to Windows 10. It still displayed the Windows 7 option on that windows boot manager even though nothing was there. I operated like this for about a year and a half with no issues.

Yesterday, I had a blue screen error with data_kernel in the error name. I restarted my computer and drive 240 was no longer showing up in the BIOs boot manager. I selected drive 120 as I usually would to get to the windows boot manager, but as it tries to load it just continues to restart.

I took out drive 240 and plugged it into the SATA cables that were connected to drive 120 to see if it was the cables and drive 240 still did not show in BIOS.

I took out drive 240 and plugged it into another system through a SATA to USB 3.0. Adapter and the drive does not show up in file explorer, but does show up in device manager. In device manager, drive 240 shows up with the same label as drive 120. This has been duplicated on two different systems.

Comment: Please supply a screenshot of the partitions of each drive as they appear in Disk Management

Comment: Screenshot provided are not helpful. Provide the information I requested.  I can’t answer your question otherwise

Comment: @Ramhound Updated with screenshots of each drive as they appear in disk management.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever used a command line program called testdisk/photorec. There should a version of it for Windows,  I usually use it on Linux. It can possibly help you restore lost partitions.

Comment: where to find that pgm?

Comment: I just started looking into this, I will let you know of the results.